# Removing admin menu links in wordpress using user ID

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my code and I dont know why isnt working

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'hide_a_menu');
function hide_a_menu() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if($user_id == '41') {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comment.php' );
    }
}
```

Comment: For information, the `get_current_user_id()` function returns an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the name `edit-comment.php` try the below code.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'hide_a_menu');
function hide_a_menu() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if($user_id == '41') {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
    }
}
```